# SQL query to generate increment field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query to get MAX UID value from the database and add 1(one) to it after specific event.
This current query generates numbers correctly until the number 10 but after the number 10 it repeats the number 10 every time the query is executed. I am expecting 11 to be generated when the MAX UID in DB is 10. Below is my current query..

```
DECLARE  @i int = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(UID),0) + 1 FROM myTable
WHERE CONVERT (date, IDate) >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())) 
UPDATE myTable
SET UID  = @i 
WHERE CONVERT (date, IDate) >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) AND Id=1451
```

Comment: can you explain this part - `ISNULL(MAX(UID),0) + 1 ` ? what does that do?

Comment: ....not too familiar w/ sql server

Comment: What's your actual requirement? There may be a better solution to it.

Comment: you intend to create a unique uid per day ? is this part of some stored proc?

Comment: I am trying to generate a UID number increment by one over the max UID number in the DB for the current date records.

Comment: whats the datatype of UID?

Comment: The datatype is varchar(50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sorting of a varchar column works like:

```
1
11
12
..
9
```

which means you pick the 9 each time.

it would be better if you change the column type to int.

i hope your id is primary key and therefor unique.

```
DECLARE  @i int;

SET @i = ISNULL( ( SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int, UID))
                   FROM myTable
                   WHERE IDate >= CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
                 ) , 0) + 1;

UPDATE myTable
SET UID  = @i 
WHERE Id=1451;
```